# Myrkul, Lord of Bones and Afterlife - will I get an Enchantment AND a Spirit Token?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a creature I control with Afterlife dies while [Myrkul, Lord of Bones](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Myrkul%2C%20Lord%20of%20Bones), is on my battlefield, will both the Afterlife as well as his second ability trigger, e.g. will I get a Spirit as well as an Enchantment Token?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, you will get the spirit token from afterlife as well as the token copy of the creature.**

Both abilities (afterlife and Myrkul's) are triggered abilities that trigger off the same event, namely the creature has died.

> 603.1. Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect]. [Instructions (if any).]”

> 702.135a Afterlife is a triggered ability. “Afterlife N” means “When this permanent is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, create N 1/1 white and black Spirit creature tokens with flying.”

Myrkul has to exile the creature card it is about to copy, otherwise you get no copy. If, hypothetically speaking, you managed to get 2 Myrkuls under your control at the same time and another creature died, both Myrkuls would trigger, but only one could actually create a copy. The other would would fail to create a copy because the card it has to exile would already be exiled at that point.

Afterlife, however, does not care about what happens to the card afterwards, only the death event is required. You will get the spirit token(s) from afterlife and can also choose to get an enchantment copy of the creature.

Answer (score 0):

You do get both. When a card moves to another zone, it becomes a new object, and normally anything that refers to the original card will be unable to "find" it. However, Myrkul's ability is a triggered ability.

> 603.6. Trigger events that involve objects changing zones are called “zone-change triggers.” Many abilities with zone-change triggers attempt to do something to that object after it changes zones. During resolution, these abilities look for the object in the zone that it moved to.

Since Myrkul's ability is a zone-change trigger, it's able to "find" the creature in the graveyard and exile, even after it dies. Even though Myrkul's ability doesn't trigger until after the creature has died, and therefore technically isn't a creature anymore, Myrkul is able to exile the creature *card* in the battlefield.

If Myrkul's ability were instead worded as "If a creature would die, instead exile it and creature an enchantment copy of it", then you wouldn't get both tokens: the ability would then be a replacement effect, and it would take place *before* the creature dies, and the creature wouldn't actually die, so Afterlife wouldn't apply. A single event can trigger multiple triggered abilities, but once a replacement effect applies to an event, the original event can't be replaced, or cause triggers.